# Not able to access POSTed variables using /dev/stdin in bash

Tags: linux, bash, post, cgi

How can I access values sent with the help of `xmlHttpReq.send` in bash?

In perl I can access data sent from an html/javascript file as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI;

$query = new CGI;

$secretword = $query->param('w');

print $query->header;
print "<p>The secret word is <b>$secretword</b></p>"
```

I am trying to access 'w' in a sh script but reading from /dev/stdin is not working. Nothing gets displayed in browser.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo $(</dev/stdin)
```

How can I access the data sent via POST in sh?

Here is the html/javascript file being used:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax Example</title>
<script language="Javascript">
function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
        }
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring());
}

function getquerystring() {
    var form     = document.forms['f1'];
    var word = form.word.value;
    qstr = 'w=' + escape(word);
    return qstr;
}

function updatepage(str){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f1">
  <p>word: <input name="word" type="text">  
  <input value="Go" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("./cgi-bin/test_ajax_bash.sh")'></p>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you know how to do that in Perl, why don't you stick to Perl? Bash is probably not a very convenient tool for complex CGI coding!

Comment: because I have this embedded device where there is support of sh only. No perl/python/java/php is supported.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams `cat /dev/stdbin`?

Comment: `cat` already reads from stdin.

Comment: Oh nice. cat works fine. I can now parse the data I get via cat. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read` shell builtin command to read lines from standard input:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo

while read line; do
  echo $line
done
```

Also you don't need `""` for echoing new line. And also you can use `text/plain` mime type if you output a plain text instead of html.

Answer (score 2):

First step : make sure your actually seeing something by echoing on standard output :

```
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "Some HTML code"
```

Then use cat

```
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
cat
```

Instead of debugging in the browser, you can also sen the sript output in a file.

```
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
cat > post_data.txt
```